# Indirect function referencing table header row

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to have an indirect function in my range select to take the headers of a specific table.

```
Sub Makro1()

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("XXXX[#Headers]").Select
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Labelname", RefersToR1C1:="=XXXX[#Headers]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("Labename").Comment = ""
    
End Sub
```

Lets assume I have the right name for the table in the worksheet "SH1" in the Cell A1

My initial idea was:

`Range("[indirect("SH1!A1")]&[#Headers]").Select`

Comment: Not really getting what you mean.  The formula `=INDIRECT($A$1 & "[#Headers]")` will return the headers for the named table.  In VBA you can use `ListObject` to reference a table: `Dim lo As ListObject:Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1")` and return the header range by using `lo.HeaderRowRange`

Comment: You already defined the name of the tables saying "ListObjects("Table1")" but rather than defining the name of the table in the code it has to look for the name in the cell SH1!A1

Comment: You mean `Range(Worksheets("SH1").Range("A1").Value & "[#Headers]").Select`?

Comment: @JosWoolley thank you very much! You helped me a lot. One last thing, how do I put the selected header row in a label name?

Comment: What kind of label are you referring to? Userform?

Comment: @JosWoolley No just a simple Name in the Name manager for the selected range in the header

Comment: `Dim MyRange As Range

With ThisWorkbook
    Set MyRange = Range(.Worksheets("SH1").Range("A1").Value & "[#Headers]")
    .Names.Add Name:="NewNamedRange", RefersTo:=MyRange
End With`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the table name from a cell you can use:

```
Sub TableHeaders()

    Dim TableName As String
    TableName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(TableName)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="LabelName", RefersTo:=lo.HeaderRowRange
    ThisWorkbook.Names("LabelName").Comment = "References " & lo.HeaderRowRange.Address
    
End Sub
```

Using formula only you could use: `=INDIRECT($A$1 & "[#Headers]")`

You could create a validation list in cell A1 to list all the tables:

```
Sub CreateValidationList()

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim ValidationList As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        For Each lo In .ListObjects
            ValidationList = ValidationList & lo.Name & ","
        Next lo
        ValidationList = Left(ValidationList, Len(ValidationList) - 1)
    
        With .Range("A1").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                 Formula1:=ValidationList
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Not sure why you'd want to select the table though - you can reference it without selecting it.
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)